# Ruby on Rails: I have code in my show that calculates age, but it displays all the calculations. How do I get it so it just displays age?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<p>
  <strong>Dob:</strong>
  <%= @student.dob %>
    <%= today = Date.today%>
    <%= d = Date.new(today.year, @student.dob.month, @student.dob.day)%>
    <%= age = d.year - @student.dob.year - (d > today ? 1 : 0)%>
    <strong>Age:</strong>
    <%=age%>
</p>
```

So this code successfully takes the date of birth of a student and displays age. However when looking at the webpage it displays all of the calculations. How do I get it so it just displays age?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p>
  <strong>Dob:</strong>
  <%= @student.dob %>
    <% today = Date.today%>
    <% d = Date.new(today.year, @student.dob.month, @student.dob.day)%>
    <% age = d.year - @student.dob.year - (d > today ? 1 : 0)%>
    <strong>Age:</strong>
    <%= age %>
</p>
```

The problem is that you're using the **equals sign (=)** at the beginning of the lines of your erb template which contains the variable assignments and calculations, which prints the result of the evaluated Ruby code into your template.

Keep in mind though, that this kind of logic **should not** be in your view. Views are meant only to present html markup filled with information provided by your **models**. In this case, I think it would be a lot better to have this logic in your student model, like this:

```
def age
  d = Date.new(Date.today.year, dob.month, dob.day)
  d.year - dob.year - (d > Date.today ? 1 : 0)
end
```

And then, your view would be something like this:

```
<p>
  <strong>Dob:</strong>
  <%= @student.dob %>
    <strong>Age:</strong>
    <%= @student.age %>
</p>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: You could also move this logic into a helper.

Comment: @mysmallidea You could, but since it represents a domain logic that could be used outside a html template (an api for instance) I think it should be on the model

Comment: Strictly, it is the equal sign at the beginning of each line that is the problem. Your example still has an equal on each line. Picky I know....

Comment: @mjs I just removed the equals signs of the expressions that must not be printed on the html (the calculations and variable assignments). The ones I left are about the presented information and must remain (the value of student.dob and the age). If I removed them, none of the information would be printed

Comment: I know - I am not questioning the code, it is the description of the error. suggest modify "on every line" to "at the beginning of every line in your erb template"

Comment: @Guilherme Franco I know I'm supposed to avoid comments saying thank you, but thank you so much!! You didn't have to advise that the code was in the wrong place, but you saved me a scolding from my lecturer!!